# Vimperator input field auto completion

Tags: firefox, vimperator

Without vimperator, if I open google and type in the first word of the sentence that I want to search for, google automatically pops up a drop-down list of candidates and I and tab through it to have auto completion.

When I use vimperator, google also give suggestions, however `TAB` no longer works because it moves the focus point to other HTML elements. Is there a way to cycle through the suggestions easily?

Answer (score 0):

For me - using the up and down arrows keys allows me to cycle through the suggestions.

Also - I'm not using `Google` as search engine, but now I checked all the popular search engines and all of them gives suggestions, and on all of them the arrows keys allow you to cycle through the suggestions.

Cheers ;)